# Placing 2 angularjs date-pickers side-by-side and not top and below

Tags: html, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using 2 Angularjs-ui boorstrap datepickers. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

I would like to place the 2 datepickers side-by-side. Unfortunately, my html code places them one on top and the other below. My html code looks like this;

```
<h4>Start date</h4>
        <div class="row"">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" 
                         datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" 
                         close-text="Close" />
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                  </span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- <div class="row"> Registration start date -->   
<h4>End date</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" 
                     datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" 
                     close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How do I change the html code to make the 2 datepickers (with the header text) appear side by side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <span>Start date</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <span>End date</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened"
                   datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true"
                   close-text="Close" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened"
                   datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true"
                   close-text="Close" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Let me try this out. It looks promising!

Comment: Verified to be the correct answer. Thank you. I have marked it as the correct answer. May I ask another side question? If I want to resize the column width of the datepicker to much smaller, how can this be done in html? Thank you.

Comment: you can put datepicker in <div class="col-md-3"> div, and make empty <div class="col-md-3"> below.

Comment: Thanks. I replace all the `<div class="col-md-6">` with `<div class="col-md-3">` and it works!

May I ask where can I get documentation on this col-md-XX thing? Is it something to do with bootstrap or html?